# How can I check if two strings match or if one is null in C#

Tags: c#, string, null

I tried the following:

```
(id == title) | (id.IsNullOrEmpty) ? "class='enabled'" : ""
```

But it gives a message saying "Error    22  Operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'method group'

Can anyone tell me what's wrong. Both id and title are strings.

Comment: A good practice is also to test for null first wherever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using bitwise OR (|).  You need logical OR (||).

```
if ( id == null || id == title )
{
   // id is null or id equals title.
}
```

Note that the equality operator (==) is case sensitive.  To do a case insensitive comparison use the static method String.Compare.

```
if ( id == null || String.Compare( id, title, true ) == 0 )
{
   // id is null or id equals title (ignoring case).
}
```

Comment: Another way would be using one of the String.Equals override which returns boolean instead of number:   `String.Equals(id, title, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);`

Answer (score 10):

Looks like you're using `|` instead of `||` and I'm not sure if you have `IsNullOrEmpty` defined as an extension method but you're mussing the `()` to invoke it.  That or just call `String.IsNullOrEmpty` directly.

Try the following

```
(id == title || String.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) ? "class='enabled'" : ""
```

Comment: @JafedPar - It says Error 22 The name 'String' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Rubin trying `System.String` or adding `using System;` to the top of the file.  Or use all lowercase `string`

Comment: @JaredPar: I prefer using string.Empty instead of "". Just for sake of readibility.

Comment: @Jaakko I don't have a strong preference either way. The OP used `""` so I just kept their notation.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a C# developer, but try || instead of |. The difference between the operators is explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691310(v=vs.71).aspx.

Also, is `==` the correct way to compare strings in C#? In Java you need to use `.equals()`.

(UPDATED: apparently | is nothing to do with the bitwise operator).

Comment: An the fact he missed the parenthesis off the method call, and that he tried to call  a static function from string on an instance of a string.

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with "bitwise" operators. When applied to operands of type `bool`, `|` is the *non-short-circuiting boolean OR*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test for "Is this string null (or empty) or equal to another string", then just say that:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) || id.Equals(title))
{
    // Code here
}
```

As a ternary operation:

```
var result = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) || id.Equals(title) ? "class='enabled'" : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this instead:

```
(id == title) || id.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "class='enabled'" : ""
```